# Is Haskell Curry's unconventional way of defining True(x) incorrect?

Tags: philosophy, provability

## Is Haskell Curry's unconventional way of defining True(x) incorrect?

Correct in the sense that: Successor(Successor(Successor(0))) = 3 is correct and thus true and Successor(Successor(Successor(0))) = 7 is incorrect and thus untrue.

> We begin by postulating a certain non void, definite class {E} of
>   statements, which we call elementary statements...
>
> The statements of {E} are called elementary statements to distinguish
>   them from other statements which we may form from them or about them
>   in the U language...
>
> A theory (over {E}) is defined as a conceptual class of these
>   elementary statements. Let {T} be such a theory. Then the elementary
>   statements which belong to {T} we shall call **the elementary theorems
>   of {T};** we also say that these elementary statements **are true for
>   {T}.** Thus, given {T}, an elementary theorem is an elementary
>   statement which is true. A theory is thus a way of picking out from
>   the statements of {E} a certain subclass of true statements…
>
> The terminology which has just been used implies that the elementary
>   statements are not such that their truth and falsity are known to us
>   without reference to {T}.
>
> Curry, Haskell 1977. Foundations of Mathematical Logic. New York:
>   Dover Publications, 45

**"... the elementary theorems of {T} ... are true for {T}."**

In the middle of his third paragraph above Haskell Curry seems to be defining
 semantic True({T}, x) on the basis of syntactic Theorem({T}, x). Is this correct?

There is no recursive structure in "A theory (over {E}) is defined as a conceptual class of these elementary statements. Let {T} be such a theory." It is merely a collection of statements. It is perhaps unfortunate that Curry uses the term "elementary theorems" which seems to have induced in you unintended baggage related to recursive definability. – Eric Towers

**In its most generic sense a theorem of a formal system could be construed as the decision of membership of the membership algorithm of the recursive language defining this formal system.**

A language L on Σ is said to be recursive if there exists a Turing machine M that accepts L and halts on every w in Σ+. In other words, a language is recursive if and only if there exists a membership algorithm for it. (Linz 1990:288).

Linz, Peter 1990. An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata. Lexington/Toronto: D. C. Heath and Company.

Comment: Why do you believe this is unconventional?

Comment: @EricTowers He totally skips all the conventional model theory stuff, and says:  "Then the elementary statements which belong to {T} we shall call the elementary theorems of {T}; we also say that these elementary statements are true for {T}"  Theorem(x) is the basis for True(x).

Comment: What semantics of Theorem(x) do you believe are being used in the quoted passage?

Comment: @EricTowers The passage seems to be saying that syntactical Theorem(x) defines semantic True(x).

Comment: The passage says from the collection of wffs, denoted {E}, declare a subcollection, denoted {T}, to be true.  There is nothing of the semantics of Theorem(x) in this quotation.

Comment: @EricTowers "theorems of {T} ... are true for {T}." Isn't True(x) inherently semantic and Theorem(x) inherently syntactic?   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth-conditional_semantics

Comment: Following your edit:  Describe the semantics of "Theorem({T}, x)" in plain language.

Comment: @EricTowers If we assume that True({T}, x) is inherently semantic then Curry is stipulating that Theorem({T},x) defines True({T}, x).

Comment: Until you define the (meta-)semantics of "Theorem({T},x)", your sentence is unevaluatable.

Comment: @EricTowers It seems to me that Theorem({T},x) is purely syntactic thus has no semantics at all.

Comment: You currently claim that "Theorem({T},x)" is meaningless.  Therefore, you are wasting our time arguing about meaningless things.  Assuming you are not just wasting our time...  Common semantics of "Theorem({T},x)" are of the shape "x follows from {T} using logic L".  Feel free to express the semantics you intend by your notation "Theorem({T},x)" and/or explain how the quoted passage incorporates those semantics.

Comment: @EricTowers I can only use an approximation of the conventional terminology. Theorem({T},x) would mean that there is a membership algorithm in the recursive language of U that decided membership of x in T.

Comment: [H.Curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_Curry) was a "formalist" (see [Outlines of a Formalist Philosophy of Mathematics (1951)](https://books.google.it/books?id=tZHrBQgp1bkC&printsec=frontcover)). Thus, he is simply saying that the true statements of a tehory are the statements provable in the theory.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Is there any objective reason why this view should  carry less weight than the alternative view posited by Gödel's 1931 Incompleteness Theorem?

Comment: @polcott - according to G, there is an objective mathematical truth irrespective of the fact that we can prove it or not. Thus, the "collection" of arithmetical truths cannot be exhasuted by the sentence provable from Peano's axioms.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA "according to G, there is an objective mathematical truth irrespective of the fact that we can prove it or not." Thus when formalism contradicts this neither view carries more weight than the other thereby making 1931 Incompleteness and Tarski Undefinability merely a point of view and thus not any fundamental mathematical principle.

Answer (score 2):

After extensive commenting, OP has established "Theorem({T},x)" to mean "there is a membership algorithm in the recursive language of U that decides membership of x in T."

The answer to your question is:  No.  Curry makes no requirement that membership in {T} is decidable in U or in {E}.

Curry follows the standard ([model theoretic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory#First-order_logic) for first-order logics) method of asserting a theory, defined as a particular collection of sentences, to be true, then determining whether that theory is satisfiable by some model.  (Satisfiability, completeness, and consistency relate this model theoretic method to the recursive decision scheme you have in mind.)

Comment: It seems to me that Curry defines True({T},x) as Theorem({T},x) leaving undecidable expressions of U as untrue. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_as_failure

Comment: @polcott : Nothing in your quote supports this position.

Comment: There is **no** recursive structure in "A theory (over {E}) is defined as a conceptual class of these elementary statements. Let {T} be such a theory."  It is merely a collection of statements.  It is perhaps unfortunate that Curry uses the term "elementary theorems" which seems to have induced in you unintended baggage related to recursive definability.

Comment: "... the elementary theorems of {T} ... are true for {T}." indicates that he is proposing that the basis of true(x) is theorem(x) which indicates provable(x) because all theorems are provable. This also makes moot how Theorem(x) is decided. If by whatever provability means Theorem(x) is decided this entails that True(x) is Provable(x).

Comment: @polcott :False.  "elementary theorems" does not implement the semantics of "Theorem()".  "Elementary theorems" is a synonym of {T}, a not-necessarily-recursively defined subcollection of {E}.

Comment: So a theorem is not a theorem? It seems to me that what he means by "elementary theorem" is the modern term of "axiom", so we are back to True(x) is Axiom(x) which is Provable(x).

Comment: @polcott : He defines {E} to be a collection of statements deemed true.  He applies the label "elementary theorems" to this collection.  There is no distinction between axioms or their consequences in Curry's definition of {E}.  You may choose to think of {E} as a collection of axioms, but this is as "useless" as taking a group to be generated by its elements or a vector space to be generated by all of its vectors -- true, but useless.

Comment: @polcott : Provable(x) is not a predicate on {E}.  There is no notion of proof here.  There is no chaining of statements.  There is no distinguished set of axioms from which other statements follow.  {E} is a monolithic block of true statements without any structure.

Comment: The provability of an axiom it is membership in the set of axioms. He distinguishes a set of statements that are stipulated to be true. How is that not an axiom?

Comment: There is no collection of axioms here.  At best there is a collection of axioms union consequents.  Without a mechanism for inference, there is no sense to distinguishing axioms from non-axioms.  You seem hell-bent on crushing the language of recursive definability from axioms to theorems on Curry's structure, but that language *does not apply*.

Comment: @polcott : There is no stipulation that {E} is closed or consistent under that inference mechanism.

Comment: It seems to me that we really can't read anything more into what Curry said besides the fact the {E} is defined by a set of expressions of U that have been defined to have the semantic property of Boolean true.

Comment: @polcott :  Yes.  Exactly.  100%.  This is how (first-order) model theory proceeds.  The follow-on questions are:   Is {E} satisfiable?  If {E} is unsatisfiable, what is a minimal unsatisfiable subcollection?  If satisfiable, is {E} finitely generated by members of {E}?  If satisfiable, is {E} finitely reachable from at least one finite generating set?  This is where the notions of axiom and theorem enter the picture.

Comment: @polcott : Are you familiar with the theory of groups (the associative algebraic structure with one invertible operation)?  Curry's {E} is analogous to giving a group presentation by saying "the group is generated by all of its elements" -- true, but structureless.  Follow-on questions are: Can it be finitely generated?  Can it be finitely presented?  These are where structure appears.

Comment: I envision the whole body of analytic knowledge defined as a recursive language of finite strings such that its membership algorithm decides True(x) for every element in this body and all expressions of language of undecidable decision problems are decided to be rejected as members.

Comment: I never got into mathematical groups. I always examine these things at the higher level of abstraction of the philosophy of logic.

Comment: @polcott : Model theory takes one step back from the recursively definable point of view.  What if we just have blobs of statements deemed true, a.k.a. a theory.  Is there any framework to understand these theories?  For first-order theories, compactness is a relationship between satisfiability of a theory by a model and consistency of the blob of statements, which relates the model theoretic content to the recursive decision problem framework you are thinking of.  However, model theory is not restricted to first-order theories.

Comment: I am envisioning a single (recursive language) theory [body of analytic knowledge] that encompasses every expression of language (expressed as finite strings) that can be verified as true entirely on the basis of its semantic meaning stipulated as relations between finite strings. Such a system would seem to be complete and consistent by rejecting some expressions of language (undecidable sentences) as semantically ill-formed by its membership algorithm.

Comment: @polcott : If you restrict to first-order sentences, you may have some success.  Second-order (and higher order) theories are much hairier.  Good luck!

Comment: It we simply define True(AK, x) to be Theorem(AK, x) on the basis of Membership(AK,x) then all of the undecidable sentences are simply decided to be ~True(AK, x). Incompleteness, undecidability, inconsistency and undefinability are abolished.

Comment: I updated my question to make it more clear. This update shows how your answer misses the mark. Also several different very high ranked members (including @MauroALLEGRANZA above) agree that Curry is saying "truth is provability" in the same sense of my update to my question, thus not in any model theory sense.

Comment: @polcott : You are thoroughly misrepresenting MauroALLEGRANZA's "there is an objective mathematical truth irrespective of the fact that we can prove it or not. Thus, the 'collection' of arithmetical truths cannot be exhasuted by the sentence provable from Peano's axioms."  He explicitly states that {E} is not distinguished by a recursive process; it is an a priori monolithic collection of true sentences.  Furthermore, you place your question in the context of the quoted passage, no part of which agrees with your interpretation.  **No one** is agreeing with you.

Comment: Look at his other reply: >>>H.Curry was a "formalist" Thus, he is simply saying that the true statements of a theory are the statements provable in the theory. – Mauro ALLEGRANZA<<< within the context of a reply to this question in another forum: >>>"truth is provability" is quite a conventional stance for intuitionists that Curry was sympathetic to. – Conifold<<< Then we can see that "truth is provability" is an alternative and legitimate point of view >>>In intuitionism, knowing that a statement A is true means having a proof of it.<<< https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/#BHKInt

Comment: @polcott : Curry's words outside of the context you have established to **this Question** are not relevant to this Question.

Comment: It is not outside of the context of the actual question itself as two very high ranking members have indicated by their replies. It is the actual question itself that I need to have answered.

Comment: "He explicitly states that {E} is not distinguished by a recursive process; it is an a priori monolithic collection of true sentences. Furthermore, you place your question in the context of the quoted passage, no part of which agrees with your interpretation." In the context of the quoted passage you are correct. I did not fully realize that this quoted passage had such limited scope when I quoted it. This was the first time that I ever encountered anyone every saying that "truth is provability" besides Wittgenstein in his "notorious paragraph".

Comment: This reply that I just quoted would make a much better answer than the one that you currently have. It turns out that how provability is defined is moot so I would strike your first two paragraphs. Even a monolithic collection of true sentences (AKA axioms) are provable on the basis that they are axioms. You are incorrect in that the quoted passage has anything to do with model theory.

Comment: I have completely answer **the Question that is asked here**.  You may well have discovered the Question you asked is not the question you want answered, but that is not my error nor a fault in this answer.  And *appeal to authority* changes no aspect of this.  You continue to assert there are provability semantics in the quoted passage and you continue to be transparently wrong.  I am done allowing you to waste my time with your empty badgering.

Comment: That seems fair. I will add some additional context to show that the question that I asked in its original context was not sufficiently answered.

Comment: @polcott : ... and I will downvote for your moving the goalposts long after answers were given, changing the Question into some other question.

Comment: If you think that this is unreasonable then I won't do it. The thing is that if Curry's quotes above are correct, then the Tarski Undefinability proof is incorrect because Tarski counts true in his meta-theory along with unprovable in his theory as proof of incompleteness. The last quote of Curry says that you can't mix and match like that.